# Python Curses Backspace detection works in main window but not in subwindows

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, curses, python-curses

I've written this function that takes user input of a specified screen for a specified length:

```
def get_str(scr, max_len):

    curses.echo()
    curses.curs_set(2)

    usr_in = ''
    cur_len = 1;
    tmp = scr.getkey()   

    while(tmp != '\n' and cur_len < max_len):
        if tmp == 'KEY_BACKSPACE' and cur_len > 1:
            cur_len -= 1                
            usr_in = usr_in[:-1]
            curs_pos = scr.getyx()
            scr.addstr(curs_pos[0], curs_pos[1], " ")
            scr.move(curs_pos[0], curs_pos[1])
        else:
            usr_in += tmp
            cur_len += 1
        tmp = scr.getkey()

    if(cur_len == max_len):
        usr_in += tmp

    curses.noecho()
    curses.curs_set(0)

    return usr_in
```

I'm using curses.wrapper with a main function that sets up all of the windows.  When I call get_str in the main window given by wrapper, the function works as intended.  Hitting backspace takes the last character off of the screen and moves the cursor backwards.  However, when I call this in a subwindow of the main window, '^?' is displayed and does not trigger the if tmp == 'KEY_BACKSPACE' statement.  This is how I set up a subwindow:`

```
def main(stdscr):

    lines = curses.LINES - 1
    cols = curses.COLS - 1

    board = stdscr.subwin(curses.LINES, int(3*(curses.COLS/5)), 0, int(curses.COLS/5) + 1)
    board.border()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subwindows don't inherit the [**`keypad`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad) setting.  When you create a window, you'll have to set that, if you want to read keys that send "any" of the named **`KEY_`** symbols.